# What exactly is the pkexec bug and how to patch it on CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, vulnerability, centos

[There is bug in `pkexec` program](https://www.theregister.com/2022/01/26/pwnkit_vulnerability_linuix/), [CVE-2021-4034](https://blog.qualys.com/vulnerabilities-threat-research/2022/01/25/pwnkit-local-privilege-escalation-vulnerability-discovered-in-polkits-pkexec-cve-2021-4034), which when exploited allows access to root shell.

Is the best way to fix an unpatched CentOS 7 server to just apply the temporary fix of running `chmod 0755 /usr/bin/pkexec`, and then patching it when a proper fix is available?

Comment: The best current workaround is `chmod 0755` until the proper patch is developed and deployed.

Comment: *"What exactly is this bug and how does the exploit actually work?"* - I think this information is easy to find by just googling [pkexec bug technical analysis](https://www.google.com/search?q=pkexec+bug+technical+analysis) - the first hit I currently get is [this analysis from Qualys](https://blog.qualys.com/vulnerabilities-threat-research/2022/01/25/pwnkit-local-privilege-escalation-vulnerability-discovered-in-polkits-pkexec-cve-2021-4034). I don't see a need to duplicate it here.

Comment: How does it work? Read the numerous articles on the topic, including the links I added to your question. When is a patch for this particular OS coming? You are going to have to ask CentOS about that. I went to the CentOS forum and found: https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=78687

Comment: Is the best temporary fix to `chmod`? Well, that's what those who found the vulnerability say. I'm not sure why you are asking or what you are looking for. Are you asking if that is enough?

Comment: A proper fix is available, the patched polkit package has been released. Just do a yum update